# Line 22: Char 5: error: non-void function does not return a value in all control paths [-Werror,-Wreturn-type] }

Tags: c++

I am getting this error. Can anyone help me with that?

```
`class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> rearrangeArray(vector<int>& nums) {
        int n = nums.size();
        vector<int> temp; 
        int pos=0, neg=1;

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            if(nums[i]>=0) {
                temp[pos] = nums[i];
                pos+=2;
            } else {
                temp[neg] = nums[i];
                neg += 2;
            }
        }

        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            return temp;
        }
            
    }
    
};`
```

I had try the return type as return temp;
but not working

Comment: Do not use the `dsa` tag.  Your question has nothing to do with `Digital Signature Algorithm`.

Comment: Consider the case `n == 0`. What do you think you're returning? (But why is there an unconditional return, and nothing else, inside a loop?)

Comment: Also, `temp` is empty, so assigning to any of its non-existent elements is undefined. Read about vectors in your favourite C++ book.

Comment: My guess is that you tried to `return` n times to get n values out. That is not needed, a `return temp;` will return everything. The *real* problem is that `temp.size()` is zero, so all the indexing is out of range.